# Sbt, local sbt plugin, using jooq code generation plugin

Tags: sbt, jooq-sbt-plugin

I'm trying to use [jooq-sbt-plugin](https://github.com/sean8223/jooq-sbt-plugin) to generate some code.

I downloaded the code, compiled it and copied jar into lib directory, but on sbt load i get this error:

```
 [warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that th
 ese dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
 [warn]          sean8223:jooq-sbt-plugin:1.4 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10
 )
```

in project/plugins.sbt i have this

```
 resolvers += Resolver.file("lib-repo", file("lib")) transactional()

 addSbtPlugin("lib-repo" %% "jooq-sbt-plugin" % "1.4")
```

Is this plugin "detected" and cannot be loaded or sbt does't see it?

P.S.
By default plugin does not work because it depends on jooq-3.2.1 which is not available on maven and I get error - unresolved dependencies. According to plugin readme i could set jooqVersion in build.sbt to other version, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "sean8223 Releases" at "https://github.com/sean8223/repository/raw/master/releases"

addSbtPlugin("sean8223" %% "jooq-sbt-plugin" % "1.3")
```

In my `build.sbt`:

```
seq(jooqSettings:_*)

jooqVersion := "3.3.1"
```

And everything is successfully resolved. I didn't run any tasks, but since you say that the problem is in resolving `jooq`, show your `build.sbt` if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: I also [asked the plugin developer on github](https://github.com/sean8223/jooq-sbt-plugin/commit/319135b04bd2237a0399f1d7d333bcbc57dd016f#commitcomment-5715832) about that default version

Comment: I had jooqVersion before seq(jooqSettings:_*). I was thinking that seq(jooqSettings:_*) will use default version if it wasn't defined. Thanks for help!

Comment: It's a general thing about loading settings in sbt: first load defaults (`jooqSettings` here), _then_ adjust them. Otherwise they will override your custom settings.

Comment: Note that the plugin author released `1.4` version with the fix: [his comment](https://github.com/sean8223/jooq-sbt-plugin/commit/319135b04bd2237a0399f1d7d333bcbc57dd016f#commitcomment-5718108), so you can use it without setting `jooqVersion` manually.